# Background size and image working on other browsers on mobile but not on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Android OS 5.0

UnScrambled !http://i58.tinypic.com/wqq8g9.jpg - from ucbrowser Android

Scrambled !http://i62.tinypic.com/23mu4ja.jpg - from mobile chrome Android

**CSS:**

```
    .mobile_icons_home{
        background: url(/images/web1.jpg) 357px -6px;
        background-size: 518px 515px;
    }
    .mobile_icons_share{
        background: url(/images/web1.jpg) 305px 252px;
        background-size: 518px 515px;
    }
    .mobile_icons_map{
        background: url(/images/web1.jpg) 305px 355px;
        background-size: 518px 515px;
    }
    .mobile_icons_search{
        background: url(/images/web1.jpg) 512px -57px;
        background-size: 518px 515px;
    }
    .mobile_icons_extlink{
        background: url(/images/web1.jpg) 460px 46px;
        background-size: 518px 515px;
    }
    .mobile_icons_slider{
        background: url(/images/web1.jpg) -420px -57px;
        background-size: 518px 515px;
    }
    .mobile_icons_options_toggle{
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        border-radius:50%;
        background: url(/images/web1.jpg) -472px -212px;
        background-size: 518px 515px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <!--<div class="mobile_icons_options_toggle"></div>
        <div class="tablecell"><div class="mobile_icons mobile_icons_home"></div></div>-->
        <div class="tablecell"><div id="feedToggle" class="mobile_icons mobile_icons_map"></div></div>
        <div id="mobile_search_cell" class="tablecell"><div class="mobile_icons mobile_icons_search"></div></div>
        <div class="tablecell"><div id="slider_toggle_icon" class="mobile_icons mobile_icons_slider sb-toggle-right"></div></div>
    </div>
```

When I open the page on mobile chrome images get scrambled, background-position not working on mobile chrome.

Comment: Could you post some actual code you have in a Fiddle link? HTML and CSS? If you are going to have a successful question career on SO, you will need to post code along with your questions, otherwise you may get a bunch of harsh replies.

Comment: doorda.whyable.com/map 
If you open the above link, in mobile browser, in chrome, icons will appear scrambled. If you open in other browser, every thing works fine

Comment: This doesn't help us help you. Post the actual code bit you are having issues with.

Comment: Thanks jerseyetr for info. I will update with other useful data.